# How to check if PHP web server has certain extensions?

Tags: php

I am trying install Laravel on my company's servers, but I need to make sure the server meets the technical requirements.

How do I check the server that it has

- PHP >= 5.6.4
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

??

Comment: Depends on your access to the server. If you have console access then `php -m`. If you can upload a php file then use `phpinfo()`

Comment: If you are installing with `composer`, then https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have terminal access, you can just filter the output from the cli info command :

`php -i | grep <extension_name>`

e.g. `php -i | grep mysqli`

Answer (score 1):

Add a page that runs phpinfo():

```
 <?php
 phpinfo();
 ?>
```

Then delete the page after you're finished so others can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Applicable to - any servers (running PHP - CMS)

**Rename index.php** Because we are checking `phpinfo()` with index.php. So, rename server CMS provided `index.php`

`$ mv index.php index.php.back`

Create `index.php` file with `phpinfo();`

`$ touch index.php`

`$ echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > index.php`

Now open the URL of your website, you will get to know - the php extensions loading with apache/nginx or whatever web-server you're using for web.

> This is different from comman_line php.
>
> > For command line php simply check php -m | grep "extension-name"
> >
> > > or php -m